# Is there any potential problem if appending more enumeration in an the header of a library which is provided by others?

Tags: c++, enums, c++14, shared-libraries

Is there any potential problem that I shoud be aware of if appending more enumeration in an the header of a shared library which is provided by others? The code of the said libray could not be modified and recompiled through I can see them :(.

I think the enum value would be replaced by a `char` or an `int` and etc when the code is compiling. If the appended value does not overflow the underlying type, I think it should not inflence the functions of the said libaray. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Say there is enumeration named as named SeatPosition, say the original enumeration is something like this:

```
typedef enum POSITON_INFO{
FIRST_ROW_LEFT,
FIRST_ROW_RIGHT,
SECOND_ROW_LEFT,
SECOND_ROW_RIGHT,
}POSITON_INFO;
```

Now, I want to append more values to extern the function that the library offord.Just like this:

```
typedef enum POSITON_INFO{
FIRST_ROW_LEFT,
FIRST_ROW_RIGHT,
SECOND_ROW_LEFT,
SECOND_ROW_RIGHT,
THIRD_ROW_LEFT,
THIRD_ROW_RIGHT,
}POSITON_INFO;
```

Comment: This doesn't not look like a C++ code.

Comment: Who knows. Maybe they can only handle so many constants (but unlikely if there's no `COUNT` constant at the end). Maybe adding a new constant will change enum size and break ABI (shouldn't happen if the values are small and incremental).

Comment: @273K What makes you think it's not C++ code? I am really curious. This enum is used as an interface for C，but the implementation is C++.

Comment: Did you ask the authors of the library? I recommend asking the people who wrote the source code of the library (since in practice they could use hidden enum values internally)

Comment: It looks more clear just to define them as local constants and not to mess with external headers and ODR: `const Enum THIRD_ROW_LEFT = static_cast<Enum>(SECOND_ROW_RIGHT + 1);` - this is valid until new values don't overflow int range. There is still an issue if the library is updated with new values some day, or if you pass your values to the library and it will corrupt its state because of totally unexpected value.

Comment: How would the library know what to do with the new values you are adding? Magic?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The author of the shared library does not know the existence of appended values.I would add some logical to return the appended postion infor to the users.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ***I can see all the codes of the said library, no hidden enum value is internally used,any other aspects that I should be aware of?*** It's a pity I can't get any help from the anthor of the library and I can't modify the code and recompile:).

Comment: @dewaffled Because a struct defined by the aforementioned library used the enum type (named ` POSITON_INFO`) as a filed member. C++ force me to assign a POSITON_INFO type to the instance of the said struct.

Comment: Redefining the type would violate the One Definition Rule of C++, leading to undefined behaviour. You *can* cast some other value to the enum type, but how do you expect the library to handle an unexpected value?

Comment: Can you recompile the source code of the library? Are you allowed to do so? Please **edit your question** to improve it (if the library is open source, give its URL)

Comment: This question seems unclear, or perhaps contradictory.  You say this code cannot be modified, and you seem to be asking how to modify it.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think the enum value would be replaced by a `char` or an `int` and etc when the code is compiling. If the appended value does not overflow the underlying type, I think it should not inflence the functions of the said libaray. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: This really sound like a XY-Problem to me. Why do you want to extend an external enum ? Maybe wrap in a struct of you own instead, and add any additional data there ?

Comment: @John If the library is sensible, it verifies that the values you provide are what it's expecting and produces an error when they aren't. In any case, it will not have any idea how to handle the unknown values.

Comment: If you cannot rebuild the shared library from source, then you can't avoid undefined behaviour due to breaking the one-definition rule.   The tough thing with that is that you cannot reliably test for the presence of undefined behaviour, so cannot prove the absence of unwanted behaviours.   More generally, if the shared library is no longer maintained, it might be time to consider engineering a replacement (or, possibly, some form of wrapper, so your programs don't have to use the shared library directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As molbdnilo notes in the comments: No, this is not possible. It violates the One Definition Rule. It is also likely to cause additional problems, e.g. with switch statements in the compiled code. And while this example has only a few enumerators, pushing the number over 255 can affect the underlying type.